# Android how to change default SSL cipher suites for WebView HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, webview, https

I need to remove RC4 cipher suites from the default list of cipher suites presented when loading HTTPS pages in Android WebView.

It looks like it might be possible when using a HttpsURLConnection, by setting the SSLSocketFactory and overriding getDefaultCipherSuites.

However, I can't seem to get a reference to WebView's SSLSocketFactory / getDefaultCipherSuites, or similar.

My Android app needs to support 4.0+

Comment: The SSL bits are not going to be implemented in Java, as `WebView` is based on WebKit (Android 4.3 and earlier) or Chromium/Blink (Android 4.4+).